# How to convert JSON object back to `Person` object java

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to convert  JSON object back to `Person` object java, but I am getting the following error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $

Example Json file:

```
{
  "type":"set",
  "key":"person",
  "value":{
    "name":"Elon Musk",
    "car":{
      "model":"Tesla Roadster",
      "year":"2018"
    },
    "rocket":{
      "name":"Falcon 9",
      "launches":"87"
    }
  }
}
```

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(input.readUTF()).getAsJsonObject();

Gson gson = new Gson();

for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
Person person = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), Person.class);
System.out.println(jsonFile);
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Person  {
String type;
String key;
Value value;
}
```

```
@Data
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public class Value  {
String name;
Map<String, String> car;
Map<String, String> rocket;
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details about the error you are getting. Also it looks to me that your parsing cast class is a bit wrong, it is hard to understand what is the value if `entry.getValue()` for the first entry in the map, from what I see it can be `"type":"set"`

Comment: Try `Person person = gson.fromJson(input.readUTF(), Person.class);`. See [https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jsonObject` in the example represents a `Person` so you don't have to iterate the `jsonObject.entrySet()` you have to use the `jsonObject` itself.

```java
Person person = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Person.class);
```